# How to divide text into two equal columns (instead of rows) on the right of the image with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create something similar to this layout in Spotify's web interface with flexbox:

Desired result:
[image: Desired result].

The idea is that I'd like to have two equal columns, with the left and right section, where the left one would be the image with the height of 100% and the right section would be displayed in two equal columns. The problem is I can't get the right two text lines to be displayed as columns, even though I tried using flex-direction: column and flex-wrap: wrap on both parent and flex item.

Here's my code:

```
**HTML**
  <footer>
    <div class="song-info">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/56x56" alt="Song cover">
        <span class="song-name">Silent Song</span>
        <span class="artist-name">Daniel Rossen</span>
    </div>
    <div class="song-controls">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="song-volume">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</footer>
**CSS**
footer .song-info {
   max-width: 15%;
   display: flex;
}

footer .song-info span {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 50%;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
```

}

I still get this:
[image: Current state]

While I want the .song-name and .song-volume to be columns like in the initial screenshot.

Comment: Your current state screenshot appears to match your description of having "the right section... displayed in two equal columns." The screenshot from Spotify has the right section organized as rows. Is it possible you mixed up your definitions here?

Comment: Wrap your song and artist spans into a new element or use grid instead of flex (I prefer grid so you don't have to add extra elements)

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod, will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add `display: flex` and `flex-direction:column` to both of the spans.

Add a container around it, code should look like this (I did add some cute styling):

```css
footer {
  background-color: black;
  width: 400px;
}

.song-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family:helvetica;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.song-info img {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.artist-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.song-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="song-info">
    <img src="https://images.genius.com/60712a7b6cbcc792502d877fb9a170c5.1000x1000x1.jpg" alt="Song cover">
    <div class="artist-container">
      <span class="song-name">EARFQUAKE</span>
      <span class="artist-name">Tyler, The Creator</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```